# c# Anyway to Add Additional methods to List<Type>?

Tags: c#

### Problem

I have Point2D class as a base class, to store List of Points I normally use `List<Point2D>` but now I want to Add Additional Methods and Few Properties to `List<Point2D>` like ToString Method for Printing, sorting based on the specific coordinate, specific method to filter Points, I don't want to use Extention Methods.

### Things I Tried

I made a new `Point2DList` Class who inherits `List<Point2D>` class which is working fine for normal use but when using FindAll Function it now returns `List<Point2D>` but I want it to return `Point2DList`.I know I can write my own method which accepts predicate delegate but that's too much work.

### Code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleAppTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var points = new Point2DList();
                points.Add(new Point2D(0, 0));
                points.Add(new Point2D(10, 0));
                points.Add(new Point2D(10, 10));
                points.Add(new Point2D(0, 10));
                Console.WriteLine(points.ToString());
                Point2DList newPoints = points.FindAll((x) => x.X == 10);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Point2DList : List<Point2D>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("List of Points");
            foreach (var pt in this)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(pt.ToString());
            }
            return sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Point2D
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Point2D(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{X},{Y}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't want to use Extention Methods." Why not?

Comment: "I want to bang in a nail, but I don't want to use a hammer!"

Comment: @Sweeper you can't override `ToString` in an extension method (in the example); but I do agree - extension methods are the logical option for most of this; OP could use a `ToPointString()` (naming is hard) extension method for that small wrinkle

Comment: @SweeperThis is just Sample Code Original Code has Lot more methods like SortByXCoordinate, FilterBy, SortByDistance, and Additional Property as well as constructor

Comment: You'll probably want to create your own list type that implements the relevant list interfaces then.

Comment: How about defining Point2DList with List<Point2D> as a field inside of it, rather than inheriting from it(Composition over inheritance). You can go ahead and define your own methods inside of the new class and use them.

Comment: ".I know I can write my own method which accepts predicate delegate but that's too much work." Huuum? Why is a predicate much work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It´s rarely neccessary to **inherit** from any collection-type - in particular as you just want to **extent** it, not **change** its implementation. Thus I´d go for [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and use a field instead:

```
class Points2DList
{
    private List<Point2D> _points;

    public Points2DList(List<Point2D> points) { _points = points; } 

    public override string ToString() { ...}

    public void Add(Point2D p { _points.Add(p); } // delegate to implementation of your underlying list

    public Point2D this[int i] // delegate to implementation of your underlying list
    { 
        get => _points[i]; 
        set => _points[i] = value; 
    }

    public Points2DList FindAll(Predicate<Point2D> P) 
    {
        return new Points2DList(_list.FindAll(p));// delegate to implementation of your underlying list
    }
}
```

This way you can control **which** functionality you really want to expose to clients. Using inheritance would expose **every** public member to the outside, which you probably don´t want. E.g. while you want to allow removing an element from your list, you may not want to enable clients to call `Clear` on it.

Comment: I Choose Inheritance because i want to use Add,AddRange , Point[id] direcly Without Specify Points Property

Comment: @Calculator You can still do that without inheritance, just delegate a call to `myPoints` to the internal lists implementation as seen in my `Add`-method.

Comment: This is the best Option So far. Let me try out few more things. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just pass it to a new list. In Linq, the same thing happens when you for example call AsReadOnly or ToList etc.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleAppTest
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var points = new Point2DList();
                points.Add(new Point2D(0, 0));
                points.Add(new Point2D(10, 0));
                points.Add(new Point2D(10, 10));
                points.Add(new Point2D(0, 10));
                Console.WriteLine(points.ToString());
                var newPoints = new Point2DList(points.FindAll((x) => x.X == 10));
                
                Console.WriteLine(newPoints.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            
            
        }
    }

    public class Point2DList : List<Point2D>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("List of Points");
            foreach (var pt in this)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(pt.ToString());
            }
            return sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
        }
        
        public Point2DList()
        {
        }
        
        public Point2DList(IEnumerable<Point2D> ls)
        : base(ls)
        {           
        }
    }

    public class Point2D
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Point2D(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return X + "," + Y;
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WJM1O1

Comment: yes, this is one of Option. Quick Question why did you change ToString Method?

Comment: @Calculator because donetfiddle could not handle it for some reason ;)

Comment: It is working with .Net Core